# Select unique records from different tables with minimum sum

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with 3 tables. Each of these tables have two columns: name and value such that all the tables have the same records (name) but different values. How do I select the records that are a part of least sum of values spanning across these tables such that the record names are unique?

**Names**: Steven, Jamie, Michael, Jordan, Gary

**Values**

(in the order of names)

Table 1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Table 2: 2, 3, 1, 5, 6

Table 3: 9, 0, 2, 11, 3

The output should return (Steven, Michael, Jamie) because the sum of the values in this case would equal to 2 which would be the least possible.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: Updated with an example of database records.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Because of my poor English, I might not have understood the question..

If you want to select across the tables, you can use "union" and sum these records.

like below?

```
select name, min(value) as value from 
(
    select name,sum(value) as value from 
      (
        select name,value from tableA
        union select name,value from tableB
      ) x group by name
    union select name,sum(value) as value from 
      (
        select name,value from tableB
        union select name,value from tableC
      ) x group by name
    union select name,sum(value) as value from 
      (
        select name,value from tableA
        union select name,value from tableC
      ) x group by name
) z
group by name
order by value
limit 3;
```

[Run at SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b3b8b/13/0)